# Product Configuration wizard error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, central-administration, configuration

**Manage server in this farm** not showing my SharePoint 2010 server.

All SharePoint site are working fine.

As the SharePoint server not showing, i cant see services under **Manage service on server**. Product configuration wizard also giving an error.

[image]

Product configuration wizard error
[image]

[image]

Comment: In a PowerShell window,run `get-spproduct -local`

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE its showing true

Comment: after running the command, reset the timer and admin service...then check if things are showing on central admin

Comment: not showing....

Comment: try to start the SQL server, and make sure SQL services is running under proper account.

Comment: can i disconnect and reconnect it again?

Comment: Are there errors in the log file (PSCDiagnostics_xxxxxxx.log) referenced in the screenshot?

Comment: it shows that either user didn't have enough permission or firewall issue and not connected. User is administrator and no issue of firewall

Comment: @RajeshJoshi Can you examine registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Web Server Extensions\14.0\Secure\ConfigDB` at the server? Content & ACL too

Comment: yes it is there

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below mentioned steps.

1. Clear the `Cache.ini`:

   1. Go to Location `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\Config`
   2. Now we can able to see the GUID’s
   3. In Right hand side Corner top Search like cache.ini
   4. Open the `cache.ini` and reset the value to `1`
2. Run the Command `stsadm -o execadmsvcjobs`
3. After that finally run
   `Psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force`

Comment: it is production server. can we do that in prod?

Comment: Yes you can do it... Don't worry, it will not affect to anything. :)

Comment: if we disconnect the server and reconnect it again, it will create any problem?

Comment: Why you want to disconnect the server?

Comment: it already shows disconnected. I am not able to deploy solution also

Comment: If you reconnect the server than it will affect SharePoint search functionality

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/wnO2v.png

Comment: After disconnecting from farm. Please follow this http://splog.cairo.ag/2011/02/22/using-sql-server-alias-names-with-sharepoint-server-2010/ & you will get it...

Comment: Database server is connected and SharePoint running fine

Comment: Thanks.. If you feel my answer works than please mark it so others can get help from it.

Comment: Database server was already connected, configuration wizard shows disconnected